# Overloading Extraction and Insertion Operators C++

Tags: c++, overloading, extract, insertion

Hello i've overloaded the insertion and Extraction operators. when i run my program the Insertion does not seem to output the values although the Extraction is putting the values into the class.
Its seems like the insertions view of the instance has no values in it.

Main

```
/ Input Poly
cout << "Input p1: " << endl;
Polynomial P1;
cin >> P1;

// Output Poly
cout << "p1(x) = " << P1 << '\n' << endl;
```

Class function

```
//Insertion
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Polynomial Poly){

for (int i=0; i < Poly.polyNum; i++) {
    os << Poly.poly[i] << " x^" << i;

    if(i != Poly.polyNum - 1){
        os << " + ";
    }
}

return os;
}

//Extraction
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Polynomial Poly){

int numP = 0;
int * tempP;

is >> numP;

tempP = new int [numP+1];

for (int i=0; i < numP; i++) {
    is >> tempP[i];
}

Poly.polyNum = numP;

Poly.poly = new int[Poly.polyNum +1];

for (int i=0; i < Poly.polyNum; i++) {
    Poly.poly[i] = tempP[i];
}

return is;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Polynomial Poly)
```

should be

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Polynomial& Poly)
```

What you're doing now is simply changing the members of a **copy** of your object:

```
Polynomial P1;
cin >> P1;
```

`P1` is not modified after this.